# What's a good tag for boring questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Boring as in boreholes.  They are interesting questions!  I think they deserve their own tag.

Here are just a few:

[3d borehole view for ArcScene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63035/3d-borehole-view-for-arcscene)

[How to digitize directional drilholes from scanned vertical sections?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6790/how-to-digitize-directional-drilholes-from-scanned-vertical-sections)

[How to convert Distance, Azimuth, Dip to XYZ?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13484/how-to-convert-distance-azimuth-dip-to-xyz)

[How to create a layer of directional/horizontal wells?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52235/how-to-create-a-layer-of-directional-horizontal-wells)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should create a [borehole](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borehole) tag.

Tags have the flexibility that they can be used for myriad purposes.  This is one that I would call a topic tag or maybe an industry tag.

One type of tag which is used extensively on the [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com), but I have not yet seen used here much is a geographic tag.  Using my own country as an example, I find it useful when questions about Australian coordinate systems (GDA94, MGA Zones), Australian metadata (ANZLIC), Australian units of measurement (metres), etc are tagged with [australia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia).

The rule of thumb for me as to when to create a new tag is whether I could see it being used on a few hundred questions over the next few years.  The other rule of thumb I use is that if a tag is being applied to thousands of questions (e.g. [arcgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis), [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis)) it is sensible to split it (e.g. [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop), [arcgis-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-server)).  Likewise, if a tag has been around a few years and only used a handful of times I think it could be better synoymised with something more generic but related.

I think these rules of thumb help to maintain an appropriate level of granularity and usefulness, and above all help funnel questions to those with that particular expertise to supply the high quality answers we aspire to provide.

Comment: Alternatively, `drilling` seems like a good industry tag. If we don't want to create a new one, there is an [`oil-gas`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-gas) tag.

Comment: boring holes doesn't imply oil-gas though. Solid cores for minerals, boring for water, traverse boring for infrastructure (electricity, water, gas, data networks) under existing objects like roads.